# Entering elliptical orbit at periapse

Tags: launch, orbital-elements

Consider a rocket entering an elliptical orbit from launch.

Say you want the rocket to enter exactly at periapse---not a few degrees ahead of it, not a few degrees behind it.

Can this be done?

I have the mathematical machinery to control a rocket launch to given altitude, velocity, orbital inclination, longitude of ascending node, and orbital eccentricity---but not argument of periapse, which would set the location of the periapse.

Between them, those variables make five unknowns to the six degrees of freedom of my rocket (three translational and three rotational), suggesting I have room to control one more variable.

That said, all the papers I've seen on orbital insertion seem to leave out the argument of periapse. Plus, the five variables I already control are the only variables targeted in the space shuttle papers that I've seen (sorry, I don't have links).

So I don't know if argument of periapse is a variable that I can target. But even if it isn't, it seems possible that it might be fully determined from the other variables over which I already have control... in which case all I need is an equation relating my desired argument of periapse to the other orbital variables.

Is there such an equation?

Comment: No need for super precision---to within a reasonable margin of error. I ask because I'm simulating a launch and have control over all key variables except the argument of perigee---altitude, velocity, orbital eccentricity, orbital inclination, longitude of ascending node. I don't expect control over true anomaly, as that would overly constrain my orbital insertion (I would need to use throttle for that extra degree of freedom and I don't want to). But argument of periapse wouldn't overly constrain the problem. I haven't seen it described elsewhere is all.

Comment: My guess is that the argument of periapse is not a true degree of freedom, as it follows from the other variables already set (altitude, velocity, etc). The question then would be how to set those other variables in order to enter orbit at your chosen argument of periapse. An equation relating a target argument of periapse to the other orbital parameters could be all the help I need  to do this...

Comment: It seems like it would be much easier (and in cases, less-delta-V expensive) to launch into a circular orbit in the desired orbital plane that passes through the point you want the periapse to be, coast around that orbit until you get to that point, and burn to set the your semimajor axis (or eccentricity,  the two are linked when you have a specific periapsis) to where you want it to be.